# How to inform vite it should HMR on source change with a custom loader?

Tags: javascript, vite, rollupjs, hot-reload, vite-plugin-development

I am writing a plugin to get all css values from a stylus file (https://gist.github.com/hl037/560b25c7ecab65bc4d2c709541794724)

It works, however vite does not hot reload it when the style file has changed.

How do you inform vite of the source file you used in the `load()` function such that it reload the module on change ?